# Searching for nickname and its count of flowers in string, JS

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, parsing

I have a string input like this:

`const text = '<Jane>:flower: <Kate><john> :like: received:flower::flower:'`

I need to write a function, which will count how many flowers each person has. Nicknames are always put into a tag with such pattern: `<nickname>`, they are case-insensitive. So every nick should be saved in lowercase.

After nick is parsed the program should search for a substring ":flower:" and count how many times it was met. If there are more than one nick which go one after the other, then they are should be chained together. So all of the ":flower:" substrings count, which go after them, should be added to every nick.

If the same nick is met twice in the text, then count of flower after it, is added to the saved count in result object.

If the same nick is met in the one chain group of nicks, for example:
`<John><John><John> :flower: <Kate>`.
Then it adds count of flowers after this chain of nicks for every time the nick was met. So, in this example Jogn gets three flowers and Kate gets none, because she has no flowers after her nick.

However, I can only use:

1. Exactly one for loop;
2. One object to store results like this:
   `{ jane: 1, kate: 2, john: 2 }`

I can't use arrays, nested loops, native JS methods (except toLowerCase()) or regex. Can anyone help me with this?

I have stuck at the idea of how to make nicknames "chained together" without using arrays. I have code like this which just returns an object, that contains all of the nicks, which text has in it.

```js
function countFlowers(text) {
  const nickTag = "<>";
  const result = {};
  let isParsingNick = false;

  let currentNick = '';
  let nickTagIndex = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    const current = text[i];

    if (!isParsingNick && current === nickTag[nickTagIndex]) {
      if (nickTagIndex === 0) {
        isParsingNick = true;
        currentNick = '';
      }
      nickTagIndex++;
    } else if (isParsingNick && current === nickTag[nickTagIndex]) {
      if (nickTagIndex === 1) {
        isParsingNick = false;
        result[currentNick] = 0;
        nickTagIndex = 0;
        continue;
      }
      nickTagIndex++;
    } else if (isParsingNick && current !== nickTag[nickTagIndex]) {
      currentNick += current.toLowerCase();
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const text = '<Jane>:flower: <Kate><john> :like: received:flower::flower:'
console.log(countFlowers(text))
```

More examples of input and result:

```
1. const text = '<Jane>:flower: <kate>:like:<John> :like: 
received:flower::flower:'
// {
//     jane: 1,
//     kate: 2,
//     john: 2
// }
2. const text = '<Jane>:flower: <kate>:flower: :flower: :flower: <John> :like: received:flower::flower:'
// {
//     jane: 1,
//     kate: 3,
//     john: 2,
// }
3. const text = '<Jane>:flower: <kate>:flower flower: flower:<John> :like: received:flower::flower:'
//because between kate and john there are no valid :flower: then they 
are grouped together
// {
//     jane: 1,
//     kate: 2,
//     john: 2,
// }
4. const text = '<Jane>:flower: <kate>:like:<John> :like: 
received:flower::flower: <Jane> alsdaksdjhsa <Jane> :flower: :flower:'
// {
//     jane: 5,
//     kate: 2,
//     john: 2
// }
5. const text = '<Jane>:flower: <kate><Kim><Jacob><Emily> :like: received:flower::flower:  <Kim><Jacob><Jane>'
// {
//     jane: 1
//     kate:2
//     kim:2
//     jacob:2
//     emily:2
// }
 6. const text = ':flower: :flower: <Jane>:flower: <kate><John> :like: received:flower::flower: '
//if there are flowers not after nickname - they are skipped
// {
//     jane: 1,
//     kate: 2,
//     john: 2,
// }
```

Comment: If that function already returns something, what's your question about this?

Comment: I see no attempt at counting flowers in your code? What is holding you back?

Comment: I made you a snippet. What is `message` ?

Comment: I just don't understand how can i count flowers for a few nicks, if they go after each other and i can't save them in the array

Comment: What should happen if a flower is detected before the first nick? What should happen with `:flower:flower:` (so with one colon between the two): does that count as 1 or 2 flowers?

Comment: That count as one flower, because the second semi-colon refers to the first flower

Comment: What should happen if a flower is detected before the first nick?

Comment: What should be returned for input `<john/><luke/  :flower:` or for `<john/><luke/  :flower:>`

Comment: if a flower is before nick, then it's just skipped

Comment: as for the input, where flower is inside nickname tag, i don't think that it should be handled

Comment: It is not within a tag in the first case, because that tag is not closed. So what then?

Comment: Oh I see, then i think the result will be just: {"john": 0}. as the program has parsed first nickname, started parsing the second one, but didn't find the ":flower:"

Comment: But I don't have any certain clarifications for such case

Comment: Is a tag considered closed if there are other characters between the `/` and the subsequent `>`? If not, can it still be a valid tag? Then how must it still be closed -- with another pair of `/>`? There is a lot of specification missing from this question...

Comment: I know, that there're a lot of missings from this one. But what if we just simplify this tag to be `<` - a opening char and `>` to be a closing char. so anything what's inside of it will be considered as a nick

Comment: I don't know. It is up to you to set the specifications. Is the `/` required or not?

Comment: It's not required, I think. I just have a problem with chaining those nicknames

Comment: *"I think"*.... I'm sorry, but if you don't know for sure what the specifications are, this question has no future.

Comment: I've edited code for the new tag. It should be just like that. `<` - opening, `>` - closing,

Comment: But still, if the input is `<john><helen <mark>>:flower:` then who gets a flower? Is it `john`, `helen`, `mark` or `helen <mark>` or no one?

Comment: It's `john`, `helen <mark`. When parsing a nickname it just adds chars to currentNick ignoring any character except closing one

Comment: And when its `>` it just stops parsing nickname and starts searching for ":flower:"

Comment: Please explain in your question what needs to happen when the same name occurs twice in the input, possibly with no flowers in between. Also you write that no native methods are allowed, but you use `toLowerCase`. Can you clarify?

Comment: Is `:FLOWER:` also a flower?

Comment: I've edited the question with more detailed conditions on those cases. And the searched flowers are case-sensitive. So only `:flower:` is acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need `isParsingNick` as this corresponds to a non-zero `nickTagIndex`.

You can apply the same system for matching with `:flower:` with these specifics:

- That string should only be matched when we have encountered at least one nick
- If the match is partial and interrupted, the index (`flowerIndex`) should be reset to 0.
- If a complete match was detected, increase a flower count

For allowing multiple nicks to get a count for the same flower, you could use a linked list of nicks (as arrays are not allowed). Then, when a new nick is encountered (or end of input) and the flower count is not zero, add that flower count to all the nicks in the linked list and then empty the linked list and reset the flower count.

Here is how that turns out:

```js
function countFlowers(text) {
    const nickTag = "<>";
    const flower = ":flower:";
    const result = {};
    let currentNicks = null; // This will be a linked list (as no arrays allowed)

    let nickTagIndex = 0;
    let flowerIndex = 0;
    let flowerCount = 0;
    for (let token of text + nickTag) { // Add empty nick so to flush the remaining flowers
        if (token === nickTag[nickTagIndex]) {
            if (!nickTagIndex) {
                if (flowerCount) { // Flush flowers
                    // Assign the flowers to the nicks in the linked list
                    while (currentNicks) {
                        result[currentNicks.nick] = (result[currentNicks.nick] ?? 0) + flowerCount;
                        currentNicks = currentNicks.next;
                    }
                    flowerCount = 0;
                }
                currentNicks = { nick: "", next: currentNicks };
            }
            nickTagIndex = (nickTagIndex + 1) % nickTag.length;
        } else if (nickTagIndex) {
            currentNicks.nick += token.toLowerCase();
        } else if (currentNicks && token === flower[flowerIndex]) {
            flowerIndex = (flowerIndex + 1) % flower.length;
            if (!flowerIndex) {
                flowerCount++;
            }
        } else {
            flowerIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}


const text = '<Jane>:flower: <Kate><john> :like: received:flower::flower:'
const result = countFlowers(text);
console.log(result);
```

#### Addendum

If you want to avoid the linked list, then maybe iterate the input backwards. That way you already know the number of flowers to assign before you get to the associated nicks, and you can then assign those flowers as soon as you identify the nick.

Here is the above script updated to implement that idea. I also included your test cases here:

```js
function countFlowers(text) {
    const nickTag = "><"; // reversed!
    const flower = ":rewolf:";  // reversed!
    const result = {};
    let currentNick = "";

    let nickTagIndex = 0;
    let flowerIndex = 0;
    let flowerCount = 0;
    let addFlowerCount = 0;
    for (let i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // Traverse in reverse
        let token = text[i];
        if (token === nickTag[nickTagIndex]) {
            if (flowerCount) {
                addFlowerCount = flowerCount;
                flowerCount = 0;
            }
            nickTagIndex = (nickTagIndex + 1) % nickTag.length;
            if (!nickTagIndex) {
                result[currentNick] = (result[currentNick] ?? 0) + addFlowerCount;
                currentNick = "";
            }
        } else if (nickTagIndex) {
            currentNick = token.toLowerCase() + currentNick; // prepend!
        } else if (token === flower[flowerIndex]) {
            flowerIndex = (flowerIndex + 1) % flower.length;
            if (!flowerIndex) {
                flowerCount++;
            }
        } else {
            flowerIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// Your test cases:
const texts = [
    '<Jane>:flower: <kate>:like:<John> :like: received:flower::flower:',
    '<Jane>:flower: <kate>:flower: :flower: :flower: <John> :like: received:flower::flower:',
    '<Jane>:flower: <kate>:flower flower: flower:<John> :like: received:flower::flower:',
    '<Jane>:flower: <kate>:like:<John> :like: received:flower::flower: <Jane> alsdaksdjhsa <Jane> :flower: :flower:',
    '<Jane>:flower: <kate><Kim><Jacob><Emily> :like: received:flower::flower:  <Kim><Jacob><Jane>',
    ':flower: :flower: <Jane>:flower: <kate><John> :like: received:flower::flower: ',
];
for (const text of texts) {
    const result = countFlowers(text);
    console.log(result);
}
```

Note that now the order of the properties in the output object may follow a different order, as these properties are output in insertion order (except when they would be *indexes* -- reason why relying on the order of keys in a plain object can be risky).

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is, as I mentioned before, Kate also should get 2 flowers. Because, she don't have any ":flower:" between her and John. So the problem is to count flowers for Kate and John, if their nicknames go after each other without any flowers. Any other text between them should be ignored. For example:
`<kate><john><kate> :flower:` - here Kate gets two flowers, john gets one flower.
`<kate>some text between<john> :flower:` - here Kate and John get one flower, the text between them is ignored if it's not `:flower:` There could be more then two nicknames chained together

Comment: OK, but the effect of repeating the name is not specified in your question. Can you update? I will delete this.

Comment: I updated my answer to support the multiple assignment of the same flower.

Comment: Just noticed your test cases that you added. will look at those first.

Comment: OK, I ran this code for your test cases and get the expected results. Any other that could be problematic?

Comment: Thank you! I'm also interested if there is any way to implement this without any data structures (arrays, linked lists, etc) and nested loop? Just theoretically

Comment: Even your result object is a data structure. What is your definition for a data structure?

Comment: But here is an idea for avoiding the linked list: traverse the input string in reverse (from back to start), so that you can count the flowers first, and then get to the nicks that should get those flowers. That way you don't need the list.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that object is a data structure too, but it was allowed to use just this one to save results

Comment: I added an implementation of that idea to my answer.